# Unable to solve No value specified for parameter 1

Tags: java, mysql

hello i'm trying to run this code but i encounter this problem and i don't know where the problem is i'll be so grateful if anyone could help
this is the code

```
public List<String> AfficherParXp(String xpath) {
    List<String> lp = new ArrayList<>();
   try {
    
       String requete="select function_name from functions where Xpath= ?";
      
       pste = con.prepareStatement(requete);
       pste.setString(1,xpath);
      rs = pste.executeQuery();

     while(rs.next()) {
        
     lp.add(rs.getString("function_name"));
     } 
     
   } catch (SQLException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(LoginwithInvalidIdTest.class.getName()).log(null, ex);
   }
    return lp;
}
```

this is the error i'm getting

```
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkAllParametersSet(PreparedStatement.java:2256)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2236)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2166)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1986)
    at test.java.Login.Suite.LoginwithInvalidIdTest.getAllFunctionsOfXpath(LoginwithInvalidIdTest.java:243)
    at test.java.Login.Suite.LoginwithInvalidIdTest.Test_LoginwithInvalidId(LoginwithInvalidIdTest.java:114)
```

Comment: You are trying to add a parameter value to the `PreparedStatement`, but your query `String` does not contain the placeholder (`?`). Instead, you have concatenated the `xpath` variable (which means no need for a parameter to be added **and** a statement/query that is prone to SQL injection (in theory)**.

Comment: Use placeholder for the parameter like `String requete="select function_name from functions where Xpath = ?"`

Comment: thank you for your reply , i've replaced it by the placeholder (?) and i'm still getting the same error

Comment: How does your code look now?

Comment: String requete="select function_name from functions where Xpath =?";
      
       pste = con.prepareStatement(requete);
       pste.setString(1,xpath);
      rs = pste.executeQuery();

Comment: Interesting... Looks ok now and shouldn't throw the same exception.